# This can´t be executed since there is a symbol not found

Tags: java, symbols

I´m having trouble with this since it cannot find a Symbol. I would be happy if someone knows what is wrong.

```
public class MartialArtist{  
public static void main(String[] args){
double HP=100;
int Strength=10;
double dmg=0;    
}
public static double Firepunch(int Strength,double dmg){
dmg=Strenght*1.5;    
return dmg;
}
public static double Firekick(int Strength,double dmg){
dmg=Strength*1.8;

return dmg;
}
public static double Tackle(int Strength,double dmg){
dmg=Strength*1.6;

return dmg;
}
}
```

Comment: what logcat shows?

Comment: Please take the time to indent your code, and include the *precise* error message. (I'd also strongly encourage you to learn about and then follow Java naming conventions.)

Comment: My guess is that your error is about `Strenght`, which isn't the same as `Strength`

Comment: @AFarmanbar: It's a compile-time error, so the code doesn't run, so there's nothing in the log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your code:

Strenght should be changed to strength.